# List commits on main branch according to their merge type

Tags: git, github

git/GitHub supports:

1. the standard merge;
2. squash and merge; and
3. rebase and merge.

It appears to me that once a merge is complete from a feature branch to the main branch (through any method above), the commits look no different from others. There's also no difference to commits made directly on the main branch.

Is there any bookkeeping available through git or GitHub that lets me bucket each commit into one of four categories:

1. commit from standard merge;
2. squashed and merged commit;
3. commit from rebase and merge; or
4. commit directly on main?

Comment: At least _standard merges_ can be told from the other types: the commit has more than one parent.

Comment: “Is there any bookkeeping available through git or GitHub that lets me bucket each commit into one of four categories” Have you checked the GitHub API?